# android sqlite REAL type

Tags: android, sqlite, floating-point, decimal

I was wondering how many exact places are there for decimal number in `REAL` data type in SQLite. If it is any difference, I think version 3 will be of the most use to know.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. REAL:The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this  [sqllite documentaion](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) REAL is floating number of 8 byte as described in [IEE floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) it can take up to 52 bit in fraction means in 16 bit enviornment it will be 1.0000000000000002 (smallest number greater than 1) 16 decimal place.